# Get XML Data from API URL in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I need to get XML Data from API and store the data in Azure Data lake store and finally have a table created for this in Azure SQL DB/DWH. I know ADF can't handle XML data. How do i need to pull XML Data into azure.  I have checking some links on using Logicapps.Any suggestions or way to handle it

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not so clear about the details of your requirement, you asked "how to pull XML data into azure", so I post some suggestions for your reference.

If you want to get the xml data of your api, you can use "HTTP" action in your logic app.
[image]

Then you can use the output of the api in the next steps of your logic app.
[image]

If you want to parse the xml data, you need to transform it to json, please refer to the screenshot below.(input "json(xml(body('HTTP')))" to the content box and provide a schema)
[image]